# Writing to a test file: Error within code?

Tags: java, file, java-io

Is there an error within the following code, It does not seem to be creating the text file (numbers.txt) that I am intending? I am aware that It is supossed to create the file in the JRE System library but I cannot locate it.

```
package test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class FileReaderTest {

    private Formatter output;

    /**
     * default const
     */
    public FileReaderTest() {

    }

    /**
     * Method that enables a user to open a file
     */
    public void openFile() {

        try {
            output = new Formatter("numbers.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            System.err.println("Problem found when opening file");
            System.exit(1);// terminate
        } catch (SecurityException Se) {

            System.err.println("You dont have access to open file");
            System.exit(1);// terminate
        }

    }// end of openFile

    /**
     * Method enabling user to write numbers to file
     */
    public void writeToFile() {

        // numbers to be written to file
        Integer[] numbers = { 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

        for (Integer i : numbers) {

            output.format("%d/n", i);
        }
    }// end of writeToFile

    /**
     * Method that closes file
     * 
     */
    public void closeFile() {

        if (output != null) {
            output.close();
        }
    }// end of close file

}// class end
```

My implementation of the fileReaderTest in the Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

//file input/putput testing

        System.out.println("Opening file");

        FileReaderTest file1= new FileReaderTest();

        file1.openFile();//opening the file
        file1.writeToFile();//writing values within the file
        file1.closeFile();//closing the file

        System.out.println("Finished with file");





    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have permission to write where it is supposed to write?

Comment: It is working fine and it creates the file at the location - *Drive:\PathToProject\ProjectName\*.

Comment: Try writing it to an absolute path e.g.: output = new Formatter("C:\\Users\\currentUser\\Desktop\\numbers.txt");

Comment: or use File argument to Formatter and print its canonicalPath to find out real location

Comment: Does it not create the file within eclipse in the JRE library?

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should use [File.getAbsolutePath()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29) 
On UNIX systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by resolving it against the current user directory. On Microsoft Windows systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by resolving it against the current directory of the drive named by the pathname, if any; if not, it is resolved against the current user directory.

Answer (score 0):

your current execution dir is: `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`, check there